# Can I mount an empty qcow2 image?

Tags: ubuntu, mount, qemu, disk-image, block-device

I am trying to mount my image.qcow2 to nbd device on my linux machine using the following command:

`guestmount -a test.qcow2 -i --ro /mnt/test_qcow/`

but I get the following error:
guestmount: no operating system was found on this disk

If using guestfish ‘-i’ option, remove this option and instead
use the commands ‘run’ followed by ‘list-filesystems’.
You can then mount filesystems you want by hand using the
‘mount’ or ‘mount-ro’ command.

If using guestmount ‘-i’, remove this option and choose the
filesystem(s) you want to see by manually adding ‘-m’ option(s).
Use ‘virt-filesystems’ to see what filesystems are available.

If using other virt tools, this disk image won’t work
with these tools.  Use the guestfish equivalent commands
(see the virt tool manual page).

Only thing that I want is to mount an empty qcow2 image.
I tried some of the solutions available online but to no avail.

Pls help! :'(

Comment: What exactly do you mean by “empty”? Freshly created by `qemu-img`? If there is _nothing_ on it, not even a filesystem, what are you expecting to mount?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/598265 ?

Comment: @DanielB Yes, freshly created. I couldn't make it because it wasn't formated. In the end I used 
`sudo virt-format --filesystem=ntfs --partition=mbr -a diskimage.qcow2` command and after that I did it as on link @TomYan gave me.  Most of the tutorials on the internet miss this part where I have to make a filesystem.